# org.apache.commons.net.nntp crashing android

Tags: java, android

Hay Guy, I'm using org.apache.commons.net.nntp to connect to a nntp server, however running a simple nntp.connect(host, port) crashes the android.

Anyone got any ideas? Do java packages work with android straight out of the box? or do they need editing?

Thanks

```
import org.apache.commons.net.nntp.*;

public class newsdroid extends Activity {
    NNTP usenet; /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            usenet.connect("ssl-eu.astraweb.com", 563);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `LogCat` to debug your program? LogCat will give a pretty detailed description of where the crash occurred. And if you are using LogCat, what was the stacktrace?

Comment: It says "java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.use.use.onCreate(use.java:19)

Comment: Can you post your `onCreate` method? It seems to me that you have not intialized something when you are calling `nntp.connect(host, port);`

Comment: import org.apache.commons.net.nntp.*;

public class newsdroid extends Activity {
 
 NNTP usenet;
 
 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        try {
   usenet.connect("ssl-eu.astraweb.com", 563);
  } catch (SocketException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your variable `usenet`, by just using `NTTP usenet` its called *declaring* the variable. It just declares the variable to type `NTTP` and it has a reference to nothing, which is commonly defined as being `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

You might need to check out [**`NTTPClient`**](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/nntp/NNTPClient.html) instead, so add this into your code

```
NTTPClient usenet = new NTTPClient();
```

That is *initializing* the variable `usenet` to a `NTTPClient`.

Answer (score 2):

you haven't initialized the 'usenet' field, so you get a NullPointerException.

"NNTP usenet;" is equivalent to "NNTP usenet = null;".

Comment: How do i initialize it? i thought putting usenet.connect("ssl-eu.astraweb.com", 563); would do that?

Comment: it's going to be something like:

  NTTP usenet = new NTTP();

the documentation for that class, which you can read on the web, suggests you probably want NNTPClient instead, but the principle's the same.

you probably need to read an introductory book on Java, specifically the bits about the difference between variables and instances.